# jQuery: Can't remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a like / dislike script that works like this: 2 buttons with `rate_deal` class. When you click the like or dislike button it removes the `rate_deal` class from both buttons to prevent clicking again and then adds some classes to look better.

I have a problem. I don't know what I did wrong but I can't delete the `rate_deal` class for both buttons when I click on a button.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content_r_d_left_rate" id="deal-1">
<span class="rate_deal content_r_d_l_rate_img_up"></span>
<span class="rate_deal content_r_d_l_rate_img_down"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".rate_deal").click(function(){

        var dealIdRaw = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var dealId = dealIdRaw.replace('deal-', '');

        $('#'+dealIdRaw).children().removeClass('rate_deal');

        if($(this).hasClass('content_r_d_l_rate_img_up'))
        {
            $('#'+dealIdRaw+' > .content_r_d_l_rate_img_down').addClass('content_r_d_l_rate_img_down_i');
            $('#'+dealIdRaw+' > .content_r_d_l_rate_img_down').removeClass('content_r_d_l_rate_img_down');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#'+dealIdRaw+' > .content_r_d_l_rate_img_up').addClass('content_r_d_l_rate_img_up_i');
            $('#'+dealIdRaw+' > .content_r_d_l_rate_img_up').removeClass('content_r_d_l_rate_img_up');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong either because it works great here: http://jsfiddle.net/LCHZ7/

Comment: It works for me too. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/ZW4bh/#&togetherjs=S0DA9H4pGJ

Comment: If you add an alert you will see that everytime you click on the button even if "rate_deal" class is removed the script is executed.

Comment: @sorinu26 right, removing a class doesn't remove the event, it just removes the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a structural problem with the way you've written your code.  When you do this:

```
$(".rate_deal").click(function(){
```

That locks in those DOM objects for click handlers from now on, regardless of whether they continue to have the `rate_deal` class attached to them.  So, structurally, your click handler is NOT removed when you remove the class.

You can solve that problem by using delegated event handling like this:

```
$(".content_r_d_left_rate").on("click", ".rate_deal", function(){
```

This will then only fire the click handler when the `".rate_deal"` class is on the clicked upon object.

This block:

```
    var dealIdRaw = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var dealId = dealIdRaw.replace('deal-', '');

    $('#'+dealIdRaw).children().removeClass('rate_deal');
```

can also be replaced with any one of these options:

```
    $(this).siblings().add(this).removeClass("rate_deal");

    $(this).parent().find(".rate_deal").removeClass("rate_deal");

    $(this).closest(".content_r_d_left_rate").find(".rate_deal").removeClass("rate_deal");

    $(this).parent.children().removeClass("rate_deal");
```

I prefer the 3rd variation because it's the most resistant to breaking if you slightly modify your HTML.

The whole block of simplified code would be this:

```
$(".content_r_d_left_rate").on("click", ".rate_deal", function(){

    // get our common parent
    var parent = $(this).closest(".content_r_d_left_rate");

    // remove existing .rate_deal classes in this block    
    // so no more clicks get processed
    parent.find(".rate_deal").removeClass("rate_deal");

    // toggle classes based on what was clicked
    if($(this).hasClass("content_r_d_l_rate_img_up")) {
        parent.find(".content_r_d_l_rate_img_down")
            .addClass("content_r_d_l_rate_img_down_i")
            .removeClass("content_r_d_l_rate_img_down");
    } else {
        parent.find(".content_r_d_l_rate_img_up")
            .addClass("content_r_d_l_rate_img_up_i")
            .removeClass("content_r_d_l_rate_img_up");
    }
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for solving the problem and also for the simplified code!

Comment: I just added an alert inside the script, and I noticed that "rate_deal" class is not removed in your simplified version.

Comment: @sorinu26 - yep, there was a typo in the `.removeClass()` line (should not be a period before the className).

Comment: I didn't noticed that period, I tought that was something else. Now it's working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Since you simply want to remove the class on click to prevent further action, You can do this -

```
$('.rate_deal').bind('click',function(){

    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('rate_deal'); //this will remove 'rate_deal' class from both of them.

    //here you can put your change image for up/down thumb logic.

})
```

Comment: This won't stop the click handler just because the .rate_deal class is removed.  One has to use delegated event handling for that to be the case.